# How to find (and select) a specific point of a graph in Python

Tags: python

The code below computes the autocorrelation using `plt.acorr` for a time-series.
My aim is to find the first value (vertical bar) on the x-axis where the graph of the autocorrelation *goes below 1/e* (= 0.3679).

In the example shown below (see image), the x-axis value the code had to select would be the very first vertical bar located on the x-axis at x=1 (or at x=-1), since the graph of the autocorrelation passes below 1/e here.

In other words, the code would have to select the value 1 (the negative counterpart `-1` is not needed).

What would be an appropriate way to code this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Timeseries = [-0.213399, 0.383858, 0.162265, 0.393239, 0.018605, 
              -0.241237, 0.0230115, 0.226046, 0.137763, -0.0818484, 0.0341396,
              -0.460055, -0.201813, 0.0728111, -0.259836, -0.0302774, 0.125858]

Threshold = 0.367879441171
plt.axhline(y=Threshold, color='r', linestyle='-')
    
# Autocorrelation (AC)
plt.acorr(x=Timeseries, maxlags=4, normed=True, color="blue", lw=1.5)
plt.title("Autocorrelation")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: By "first", you mean the closest to the bar at `lag == 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.acorr` can return the resulting AC like so:

```
lags, c, line, b = plt.acorr(x=Timeseries, maxlags=4, normed=True, color="blue", lw=1.5)
```

Hence, you can do:

```
indices_below = np.where(c < 1/np.exp(1))[0]
index_zero = np.where(lags == 0)[0]

first_point = lags[np.argmin(np.abs(indices_below - index_zero))] # = -1
```

The above returns -1 because it is the "first" from left to right between -1 and +1, but you could just flip the arrays or add another condition if you really want to get 1.

Comment: Thank you, your code does exactly what I wanted to compute. I have two questions. (1). via "np.where(c < 1/np.exp(1))" you define that the autocorrelation vector has to be below 1/e. Why is it necessary to add "[0]" here? Is that required to pick the very first lag that I asked for? (2) via "np.where(lags == 0)[0]" you define that we 1/e is in reference to the y-axis, correct?

Comment: @Philipp

 1) The reason is `np.where` returns a tuple of arrays (one for each dimesion, even if the array is 1D). So we get the indices along the first and only dimension with `[0]`.
2) Yes, I am looking for the index corresponding to lag 0 so that I know which of the found indices is closest